# Why my Array of JComboBox are not updated?

Tags: java, arrays, immutability

I create a field of `Object[]` named `array`:

```
private Object[] array;
```

And then I initiate it with dimension and add `JComboBox` into it in method A:

```
array = new Object[14];
array[0] = combo1;
array[1] = combo2;
....
```

Then, I changed the data model of these `JComboBox` in method B, `changeCombo`.

```
private JComboBox<String> changeCombo(String newOption, JComboBox<String> combo, Set<String> data) {
if (combo != null) {
    int size = combo.getModel().getSize();
    data.add(newOption);
    if (size != data.size()){
        combo = updateCombo(data);
    }
        return combo;
    }
}
```

Where `updateCombo(data)` is:

```
private JComboBox<String> updateCombo(Set<String> dataSet) {
    JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<String>();
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    model.insertElementAt(Constantes.COMBO_TEXT_TODOS, 0);
    for (String s: dataSet) {
        model.addElement(s);
    }
    combo.setModel(model);
    combo.setSelectedIndex(0);
    combo.addItemListener(new ComboItemListener());
    return combo;
}
```

At last, I invoke this array again in method C, only to find all JComboBox has no data in it.

```
for (int i=0; i<14; i++ ){
    TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
    col.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor((JComboBox<String>)(array[i])));
    //here I found the data collection in each combo is empty
    col.setCellRenderer(new ComboRenderer());
}
```

So, arrays are immutable in my case? Or these JComboBox are immutable?

Comment: What is `combo1` and `combo2` where does it come from?

Comment: I just create them in the first part like: `JComboBox combo1 = new JComboBox();`, etc.

Comment: Where does `combo` argument in `changeCombo` method come from? How is it connected to `array`?

Comment: They come from the array that contains all the combos. What I want to achieve here, is 1) construct combo objects and put them in an array 2)read a serie of entities, obtain their fields' values, construt some list to store all the values of same fields for changing the values to populate all the comboboxes. Once an entity is read, check every field's value, to see if it exists in the list, if not, add this value to the list and change the combo data model.  3) find these changed comboboxes again, still in the array, to construct everyone's custom cell editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **updateCombo** you create a new instance of JComboBox, but the array contains a link to the old instances

You need to explicitly replace old instances to newer ones returned by **changeCombo**.
Something like this:

```
array[i] = changeCombo(newOption, array[i], data);
```

I think, In your case, it is better to reuse existing instance of combo - just change it's model to the newer one. Or more - modify existing model.

For example, you can replace `updateCombo` with `updateComboModel`:

```
private void replaceComboModel(JComboBox<String> combo, Set<String> dataSet) {
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    model.insertElementAt(Constantes.COMBO_TEXT_TODOS, 0);
    for (String s: dataSet) {
        model.addElement(s);
    }
    combo.setModel(model);
}
```

And just call `replaceComboModel(combo, data)` instead of `combo = updateCombo(data)` inside `changeCombo`

I may miss some swing internals,

This Oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) can also help you understand the nature of object references - see the *Passing Reference Data Type Arguments* part.

Comment: so, with `combo = updateCombo(data);` these combos are not updated in the array? But outside the array they are changed? Am I missing some basic concepts of Java here?

Comment: @FaithReaper:  Yes. This is one of the fundamentals of Java. You need to understand that you operate with object references. If you create some new instance of the object, you have to store that reference somewhere, if you want to use this object in the future.

Comment: @FaithReaper: It is not about immutability, it is about relations between java heap and stack. It is described at the very beginning of any java book. Here you can read basics of java OOP - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: Now I see it more clearly. When I do `combo = updateCombo(dataSet);`, I just make reference `combo` to point to the new object I create in the method, but array[i] points to the original unchanged object. The relation between `combo` and `array[i]` is broken, you have to make it consistent again by `=` again. Thanks a lot to make me review it again.